# Sort array by field in Angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort an array and am getting the following error.

"Argument of type '(a: User, b: User) => number | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type '(a: User, b: User) => number'."

What am I missing?
I will be grateful for your help.

```
 this.users.sort(function(a, b) {
          if (a.messagesLast && b.messagesLast) {
            return new Date(a.messagesLast.datemes).getTime() - new Date(b.messagesLast.datemes).getTime();
          }
          return ;
        });
```

Comment: Read the error message carefully. It says you are not allowed to `return undefined;` which is equivalent to `return ;`. For more details, check the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: How can i return the original array this.users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A JavaScript sort compare function needs to return a number, see [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), in your implementation it returns undefined, if one of the items doesn't have the property `messagesLast`.

In order to keep the original order in this case, you need to return `0` instead of `undefined`.

```js
this.users.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a.messagesLast && b.messagesLast) {
    return new Date(a.messagesLast.datemes).getTime() - new Date(b.messagesLast.datemes).getTime();
  }
  return 0;
});
```